# best practice add page or add post in wordpress for site like w3schools

Tags: wordpress

I am preparing the site like w3schools using wordpress.

There are two things i can add post or page.

I want to add a page which describe the doctype in HTML category.
1) Is it possible to add a page under sub-category bccause pages are added under menu.

I am having HTML, Jquery, PHP etc category and there will be subcategory under thing like doctype, li, ul, meta etc. On home page it will show all category and on clicking on category. It will show all sub-category under that.

Please guide me how to do the above.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firstly you need to make sure about the differences in `page` and `post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to implement

1)Posts: create categories and respective nested sub-categories in posts rather than pages. then put content under posts.

2) Pages: create nested pages then apply templates to the pages.

To get all categories on home page:

use get_pages() or get_posts() in an array. then loop through the array to get all top level pages and their child pages' titles.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use posts. Then you can use categories and tags.